# udev rule to create device node from character device listed in /proc/devices

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev

I have a PCI device which I've been able to configure a DKMS module for. The kernel module is loaded and I see the device appear in /proc/devices.

The driver had a load_driver.sh script which creates a device node using mknod. I want to make a udev rule that creates this node automatically when the driver is loaded. How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of using udev, I recommend you to use any of the Linux frameworks. For example, explore the `misc device` framework if you want to play around with simple char device. It automatically creates device nodes for you, with proper permissions. The advantage of this over udev is that, the code is portable across systems.

Comment: The problem is that I can't modify the driver code because it is proprietary from a thirdparty and the misc device framework require the module to be marked as GPL.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I have no idea, but I took a look at my own system.

Checking my own udev rules, I found that VirtualBox seems to do this using this udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh $major $minor $attr{bDeviceClass}"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh --remove $major $minor"
```

Subsystem in your case is probably "module". You need to find a way to identify your particular module